# mvn archetype:generate コマンドを実行しても、エラーでプロジェクトが作成できない

Tags: maven

macOS で Mavenを勉強中です。

#### 事前に行った環境設定

Homebrew で maven をインストールし、PATHを設定しました。

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

JDKもインストールしPATHを通しました。

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

```
@MacBook-Pro Desktop % mvn -version          
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/13.0.2+8_2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

#### 問題点

`mvn archetype:generate` コマンドでプロジェクトを作成しようとしましたが、下記のようなエラーでプロジェクトが生成できません。

その他の原因があると思うのですが手詰まりのためご教授いただきたいです。

```
~/Desktop $ mvn -X archetype:generate
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 14.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/taka/.m2/settings.xml
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-parseable settings /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml: end tag name </proxies> must match start tag name <settings> from line 46 (position: TEXT seen ...</proxy>\r\n  \r\n  </proxies>... @106:13)  @ /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml, line 106, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build (DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.configuration.SettingsXmlConfigurationProcessor.process (SettingsXmlConfigurationProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.configure (MavenCli.java:1166)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: 念の為確認なのですが、そのproxy設定はMacOSで行っているproxy設定と同じでしょうか。/ `-X` オプションを付けて `mvn -X archetype:generate` とするとより詳細なメッセージが出ると思いますが、Downloadやproxy周りのエラーはどのように出力されているでしょうか。

Comment: MacOSで行っているproxy設定の確認ができていませんでした。MacOSのproxyの内容にsettings.xmlのproxyを合わせれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 該当してそうな部分を貼り付けます。Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /Users/taka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom.lastUpdated
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: proxy周り：Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom ProxyInfo{host='proxy.host.net', userName='null', port=80, type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}

Comment: (コメント欄でなく、質問文を更新して情報を追加していただければ良いです。)/これも一応念の為確認なのですが、プロキシ設定というのは、あなたが利用している(例えば会社だったり学校だったりの)ネットワークを利用するために必要な設定で、ネットワーク管理者から通知されるものですが、そのような情報を正しく設定しているでしょうか。`proxy.host.net`というのはあくまで例なので、そのまま設定しても正しくありません。/Macを所有していないので詳細は分かりませんが、OSでの設定/確認方法は[こちら](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/guide/mac-help/mchlp2591/mac)になるようです。ここでproxy設定を行っていないのであれば、Mavenでも行う必要はありません。原因は別のところにあると思われます。その場合、初期状態に戻して(つまり`~/.m2/settings.xml`を削除して)もう一度 `mvn -X archetype:generate`を実行しエラー内容を確認してみてください。

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。Macで特にproxyの設定はしていません。
~/.m2/settings.xmlを削除し、mvn -X archetype:generateした結果の情報を更新しました。

Comment: 追記されたエラーは`/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml`のXML書式に問題がある(おそらく編集した`proxies`の部分が元の状態に戻っていない(正しくコメントアウトされていない))ことが原因ですので、そちらを見直した上で再度実行してみてください。

Comment: コメント頂いたとおりで、正しくコメントアウトしたらmavenプロジェクト生成できました。迅速な対応ありがとうございました。プロキシの意味が理解できました。

Answer (score 1):

質問に書かれているエラーはXMLの書式誤りを報告しており、おそらく `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml` のプロキシ設定の部分を編集された後、正しく原状回復できていないのが原因です。

元の状態では次のようになっています

```xml
  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>
```

(`<proxies><!-- ここはコメント --></proxies>`という形です)

ので、このように戻した上で再度

```
mvn -X archetype:generate
```

を実行してみてください。

Comment: コメント頂いたとおりで、正しくコメントアウトしたらmavenプロジェクト生成できました。迅速な対応ありがとうございました。プロキシの意味が理解できました。

Answer (score -1):

mavenリポジトリのURL schemeが「`https`」であるので、プロキシ設定の`<procorol>`の値を`https`にする必要があると思います。

```
<!-- 変更例 -->
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol> <!-- 注: ここの値を"https"に変更 -->
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記のように試しましたが、エラー内容は変わりませんでした。。。